# Azure Function With Parameter Name Containing Hyphen In Route

Tags: c#, routes, azure-functions

I have the following function in an Azure Functions application:

```
[FunctionName("MyFunction")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "x/{my-guid}/y")] HttpRequest httpRequest,
    Guid myGuid,
    ILogger logger
)
```

The problem is that I can't use the string "my-guid" as a parameter name because it contains a hyphen, and when I use "myGuid" instead I get a "cannot bind parameter" error message.

Is there a way to do this, perhaps by somehow explicitly stating the mapping from "my-guid" to "myGuid"?

I have tried using attributes such as `[FromRoute(Name = "my-guid")]` to decorate the myGuid parameter, but this didn't work.

Comment: Why can't you rename "my-guid" in the route to "myGuid"?

Answer (score 0):

So you have basically two issues:

## Dashes in route

The first one is "mapping" `my-guid` to `myGuid` which I am unfortunately not being able to help with - I can not recall anything that could achieve that, besides "hiding" your functions behind some sort of API Gateway (like API Management).

## Parameter binding

The second one though is your "cannot bind parameter" error, which I assume you would get even if the first issue would be resolved. Apparently functions are unable cast parameter to Guid type, change it to string and then convert to Guid inside the body of your function method:

```
    [FunctionName("MyFunction")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "x/{myGuid}/y")]
        HttpRequest httpRequest,
        string myGuid,
        ILogger logger
    )
    {
        if (Guid.TryParse(myGuid, out var guid))
        {
            return new OkObjectResult(guid.ToString());
        }

        return new BadRequestResult();
    }
```

## Side note:

It's a bit painful with this additional logic, but I think it might be simplified with use of Azure Functions in isolated process rather than in-process and benefiting from middleware that handles that logic. It would make it a bit more future-proof as well:
[image]
[Source of the image](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/net-on-azure-functions-roadmap/ba-p/2197916)